# Node.js: Is there a way to log invisible characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, console, invisible

Is there a way to see invisible characters like whitespace, newlines, and other non-printing characters when you run `console.log`?

I'm asking this because I'm debugging my code for my program and I noticed when I print the text to the console, it's about 75 length long but then I added an extra `console.log` to print the length of the text and it said it was 175 length. There are obvious characters that I can't see so I'm wondering what I can do to see these characters.

Comment: Special characters are impossible to display. By the way, could you edit your question and put the ``String``.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if I use `encodeURIComponent` I can see the invisible characters (sort of?).

*In case anyone is wondering this is what it looks like before I used it and after*

**Before:** `ffabca9ce1b26dd2a4092e9c0c5eba5c01:4678b1ac28f391cfd08e17e89dcc76e4`

**After:** `ffabca9ce1b26dd2a4092e9c0c5eba5c01%3A4678b1ac28f391cfd08e17e89dcc76e4%0A%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00`

I'm guessing this has something to go with the TCP connection.